# Accessing a Document being edited in a Outlook reading pane

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-addin

I have written a simple VSTO addon that inserts a hyperlink into an e-mail when user clicks on a ribbon bar button. Here is a code sample:

```cs
    private void button1_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
    {
        var context = e.Control.Context as Inspector;

        if (context != null)
        {
            if (context.IsWordMail())
            {
                var doc = context.WordEditor as Document;
                if (doc != null)
                {
                    var sel = doc.Windows[1].Selection;
                    doc.Hyperlinks.Add(sel.Range, "http://www.google.com", "", "", "Google", "");
                }
            }
        }
        else if (e.Control.Context is Explorer)
        {
            Explorer explorer = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveExplorer();

            if (explorer.Selection.Count == 1)
            {
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Selection itemSelection = explorer.Selection;
                var item = itemSelection[1] as MailItem;

                // get the instance of WordEditor in a reading pane?

            }
        }
    }
```

This works well when the e-mail is being edited in a separate windows (`e.Control.Context is Inspector`).

If the messsage is being replied to/forwarded and the reading pane is turned on, the editor is displayed inline in the reading pane (`e.Control.Context is Explorer`).

I can not figure out how to get the instance of the `Document` in this case. I can access the item selected in the Explorer but I cannot figure how to access the Document editor being displayed in a reading pane.

If I 'pop out' the editor to a separate window, it works fine (context changes to Inspector).

Is there a way to access a e-mail document which is edited directly inside reading pane?

---

With great help from [Dmitry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/332059/dmitry-streblechenko) who pointed me in right direction I found out that there is a property in a Explorer class: `Explorer.ActiveInlineResponseWordEditor` which gives you editor displayed inline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can call `MailItem.GetInspector`, then `Inspector.WordEditor`. This should work fine in the newer versions of Outlook. Outlook 2016 also exposes the `Explorer.ActiveInlineResponseWordEditor` property.
2. You can use [SafeExplorer](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/SafeExplorer.htm) object in [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/) (I am its author) - it should work in all versions of Outlook, and it exposes the `SafeExplorer.ReadingPane` property ([ReadingPane](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/safe_ReadingPane.htm) object).

Comment: I tried the 1st method but I am getting COMException: Out of memory. After a bit of experimenting I found out that while editor is embedded in main window, no document manipulation is possible and as soon as I 'pop out' the window, the same code is working. For example:
`Document.Paragraphs[1].Range.Delete()` is throwing the following COMException:
This method or property is not available because the document is locked for editing.

In separate window, it correctly removes first paragraph.

Comment: That's true, but when I hit reply, editor is shown directly in reading pane and that editor is clearly not read-only. If I call Document.Unprotect() on the document obtained by MailItem.GetInspector().WordEditor, the exception is no longer thrown, but also the text does not change when trying to manipulate it, so it must be different instance of editor displayed in the reading (editing?) pane.

Comment: I also tried method 2 by using your Redemption library by obtaining `SafeExplorer.ReadingPane.WordEditor` and it is working great, so I guess method 2 is an answer to my question.
I wish Microsoft deciced to expose ReadingPane in their own product in the first place :). Thank you for your help.

Comment: But you are not working with the new message that you edit - it lives in the Drafts folder. The old message that you reply to is in the Explorer.Selection collection, but it is not being edited. If you need the new inline message, you need to use the Explorer.InlineResponse/InlineResponseClose events. Or you can use the SafeExplorer Redemption object - it uses Windows API to find the embedded word editor, whatever it happens to edit.

Comment: Ah, thanks! InlineResponse is probably I am looking for. Looking at the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj229061.aspx), this feature was added in Outlook 2013 but my project is for Office 2010 since currently we have a mixed environment of 2010/2013 versions and I wanted to have a single addon for both of them.

Comment: In that case you will need to dynamically subscribe to the new event. Easy in C++ or Delphi, but I have never done that in C#, sorry.

Comment: Actually it is even simpler than that :) `Explorer.ActiveInlineResponseWordEditor` is the editor I needed.